# Telegram messages (from bot or manual) how to avoid numbers becoming links on mobile?

Tags: markdown, telegram, telegram-bot, markup, clickable

When sending or receiving message in Telegram containing numbers, I noticed they automatically become links on the mobile client if they contain 5 or more digits. Also if there is a dot in between.

For example, if there is `1234` or `12.34` in a message, all is good. However if a message contains `12345` or `123.45` or `12.345` it becomes a link. Example screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Clicking it seems to open it as some sort of phone number.

This happens with messages I send manually, as well as through bots. Only on the mobile client (Android in my case), the same message looks fine in the web client.

When using prices or money amounts, it doesn't happen where there is a symbol directly attached to the number, like `€249.95` but it *does* happen if there is space in between, e.g. `€ 249.95`.

Is there some way, either when sending messages manually or when sending from a bot (using the [sendRequest API function](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)) to avoid numbers from being automatically converted into links?

Answer (score 1):

you can set `parse_mode` on `HTML`, then markup the number as `<code>`:

```
pay <code>€249.95</code> for this service
```